# How much choice we can get from this partition principle?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, partitions, cardinal-characteristics

For every set $X$ there cannot be a partition on $X$ of a larger size than the set $\iota``X$ of all singleton subsets of $X$. Formally: $$\begin{align} \forall X \forall P: P \text { is a partition on } X \to \neg [&\exists f (f: \iota``X \rightarrowtail  P ) \land \\ & \not \exists g (g: P \rightarrowtail \iota ``X)] \end{align} $$

Where:

$$\begin{align} P \text { is a partition on } X \iff &\forall k \in P (k \neq \emptyset) \land \bigcup P = X \ \land \\ & \forall a ,b \in P (a \neq b \to a \cap b = \emptyset) \end{align}$$

Where $`` \rightarrowtail "$ stand for injections.

> What forms of Choice this principle with the other axioms of $\sf ZF$ can prove?

> Same question but with regards Stratified $\sf ZF$?

Stratified $\sf ZF$ is the theory axiomatized by the stratified axioms of $\sf ZF$, where *stratified* is defined after Quine as in $\sf NF$.

Comment: So, every partition of $X$ is either incomparable or injects to $X$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Yes! In the context of ZF.

Comment: This is known as the Weak Partition Principle.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, what kind of known forms of choice this entails? Especially from the stratified axioms of $\sf ZF$?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar IIRC, it is open whether it implies the dual CB theorem (which in turns it is open whether the dual CB theorem implies PP and it is open whether PP implies AC) in ZF

Comment: @Holo, you mean this version of PP?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar "it"=WPP=your  version of the partition principle, that is: $AC⇒PP⇒CB^*⇒WPP$ and the opposite direction of those arrows are all open in ZF

Comment: @Holo, is that the same for stratified ZF?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar any proof in stratified-ZF will certainly transfer into ZF, as ZF is an extension of stratified-ZF, so it is also open in stratified-ZF

Comment: @Holo, True! But we may know that something is NOT decidable in a fragment of a theory before we know that for the mother theory. Example $\sf AC , ZFA, ZF$.